# Changing domain password on DC fails regardless of complexity

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, domain-controller, password-policy

I have a new Windows 2008 R2 Server (Standard, German). After installation from CD I enabled RDP Access, installed the Active Directory services and executed dcpromo. After reboot I log in via RDP as Domain Administrator and run Start -> Windows Security -> Change password. This does not work. What ever password I try, i get the error message that the password cannot be changed because of complexity restrictions.

I checked the policy using rsop.msc and everything seems normal. I tried passwords like "Asdf123", "P@ssword", "Letme1n." Which all should work.

I reinstalled several times. Same result. Please help, time is running out :(

Thanks

## Solution

The Domain Password policy also has a rule for the **minimum age**. This enforces that the password cannot be changed twice within one day. This rule does only apply for Domain Controller.

Comment: What is your complexity policy set to?

Comment: It's the default. Complexity requirements apply, History of 24 Passwords, reversible encryption disabled, max age 42 days, min length 7 characters, **minimum age 1 day**
That's it. I did not realize that there is also a minimum age. Thx for asking!

Comment: t1nt1n: Okay I haven' used the platform for a while. How shall I "answer" this question? If you want to write on, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Thomas use the "Your Answer" form below to post the Solution and then accept the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out to be normal behavior inside a domain. The problem was the password policy "**minimum password age**" which defaults to **1 day**. So all user accounts including the domain administrator cannot change their password within one day.

Of course the reset password function in Active Directory Users and Computers is still working. For non Domain Computers this restriction does not apply by default. In this case a password change should be possible at any time.

Thx to the commenters. Happy new year!